# bounding box in vertex shader

Tags: opengl, vertex-shader

currently I have a simple shader that renders a static mesh into the scene. I would like to know if it is possible to have a second output in my vertex shader that gives me the 2D bounding box of my object after the projection has been applied. Something like this:

```
#version 330 core

in vec4 Vertex_ms;
in vec4 Normal_ms;

out vec4 Normal_ws;

uniform mat4 Proj;
uniform mat4 View;
uniform mat4 Model;

uniform out vec2 topRight;
uniform out vec2 bottomLeft;

void main() {
    gl_Position = Proj * View * Model * Vertex_ms;
    topRight = max(gl_Position.xy, topRight);
    bottomLeft = min(gl_Position.xy, bottomLeft);

    Normal_ws = Model * Normal_ms;
}
```

this doesn't work, because I can't write to uniforms, but the intenion is, that I can make a reduce over the projectet vertices to get a bounding box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenGL-4.3 added a few functions to GLSL that allow to implement this, namely all the functions starting with `atomic…`. Of course those require an OpenGL-4.3 capable implementation, i.e. the latest generation of GPUs.

Most usefull for you are [atomicMax](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/atomicMax.xml) and [atomicMin](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/atomicMin.xml).

However be advised that using those comes with a severe performance penality. A far better solution would be to calculate the bounding volume in advance an then just transforming that. If you're thinking about deformable meshes, keep in mind that those will stay withing certain bounds for any given deformation.

Comment: ok thank you for the info. Do you know weather it is possible that I use a transform feedback buffer to write out my projected coordinates and then use a reduce operation on the buffer to get my bounding coordinates?

Comment: It's possible to implement for sure. But it's also one of the tasks GPUs are horribly inefficient at doing. GPUs are many-to-many machines, where for each tuple of input data one tuple of output data is produced. Reducing is a many-to-few operation and GPUs actually are often outperformed by regular CPUs in such tasks. In your case an optimized solution is surely possible, since for n vertices only log2(n) comparisons must be made, which actually can be parallelized. But honestly I'd really look into if doing that BB calculation really must be done in realtime, or if it can be done offline.

Comment: thank you very much, will accept your answer. Btw my real problem is not about Bounding Boxes, they are just much simpler to explain.